# GUI search tool that searches by modified date by default?

Tags: lubuntu, gui, search, default

I'm looking for a GUI search tool that searches by modified date by default. Catfish is ALMOST perfect, but there doesn't seem to be a way to search by modified date by default.

File names (`*foo*.txt` for example) are all I'm after, nothing fancy.

I'm using Lubuntu.

Thanks so much for any help and/or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I found a pretty effective solution: I use Gnome Search Tool, which allows me to search only files that have been modified within a certain number of days. Though the results are not sorted by modified date, the number of search results is so dramatically reduced that it's never hard to find the file I'm after.